# Error when hibernating : "PM: Swap header not found"

Tags: swap, hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

My swap partition:

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda2                               partition   3144700 2460    -1
```

and in /etc/fstab:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f3ce520a-8e22-43aa-9818-b9ea4797b0c6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
/dev/sda2 none swap sw 0 0
```

then, I've edited `/etc/initramfs/conf.d/resume` since it was advised apparently. 
Using:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="f3ce520a-8e22-43aa-9818-b9ea4797b0c6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5b0282a3-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="d1720cc2-cc64-4042-b811-427f7b3c2cd8" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="5b0282a3-02"
```

I've added this single line in the `resume` file:

```
resume=UUID=d1720cc2-cc64-4042-b811-427f7b3c2cd8
```

After rebooting, I've tried to do: `sudo pm-hibernate` but I've still got the same error: `PM: Swap header not found`

I don't know what to try now...